# HDF5 file created in Fortran not written until simulation ends

Tags: fortran, hdf5, intel-fortran

I am writing an application in Fortran that dumps a single file containing several arrays at each time step. At the end of the time-step, a new file is opened and data is written to it. Each of these files is created by calling:

```
  ! Create a new file
  CALL h5fcreate_f(trim(filename), H5F_ACC_TRUNC_F, file_id, error)
```

and closed by calling the following subroutine `close_hdf()` at the end of each time step:

```
 subroutine close_hdf()

     ! Close the file
     CALL h5fclose_f(file_id, error)

     ! Close FORTRAN interface
     CALL h5close_f(error)

  end subroutine close_hdf
```

Yet, at the end of the time-step, the file is zero bytes and I have to either kill the executable or wait till all the time steps have finished
to be able to analyze the data. Why are the files not being flushed?

I have also tried to flush the data by calling

```
  CALL h5fflush_f(file_id, H5F_SCOPE_GLOBAL  , error)
```

inside `close_hdf()` but that did not help either. How do I flush and close/write these files at the end of the time step as soon as I am done with them?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Fortran - you'd have the same issue no matter which language you called the HDF5 library from.

Comment: 1. You should `CALL h5close_f(error)` only once, at the end of the program execution. 2. What filesystem is it? In principle, what you do should work, when closing the file its content should be flushed to disk anyway.

Comment: @SteveLionel The python interface is so easy that I didn't even have to learn it. That one just worked out of the box!

Comment: @PierredeBuyl It is ext3/ext4

Comment: Ok, I wanted to know whether you were on a network file system, which I didn't mention explicitly. As it is not the case, my best guess is that there is an error in the logic of the code at some other place.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl my best guess is that it is a  network file system. ASCII files are however written (and readable) at the end of each time-step.

Comment: What is the context? Is it a job running on a node of a computing cluster?

Comment: @PierredeBuyl yes. The job is serial. In other words, mpirun/mpiexec is not being used. MPI calls are dummy.

Comment: That you use MPI features or not does not matter here. The filesystem will buffer I/O and you have (as far as I know) no control over that. I have lost all hope of monitoring HDF5 files during simulation jobs.